# Changing layout background based on theme

Tags: android, themes

I am trying to style background (ant text color) of a view based on current theme.

in my attrs I have:

```
<attr name="DirectoryRowTrackName" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="DirectoryRowSmallName" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="DirectoryRowBackground" format="color|reference" />
```

In my ActionBarSherlock derived themes I have:

```
<style name="Theme.Xenolight" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_xenolight</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Xenolight</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_xenolight</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Xenolight</item>

    <item name="DirectoryRowTrackName">#000000</item>
    <item name="DirectoryRowSmallName">#aaaaaa</item>
    <item name="DirectoryRowBackground">#55ffffff</item>

</style>
```

Then, trying to apply the color:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="?attrs/DirectoryRowBackground"
android:id="@+id/cale"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="bottom" >
```

Results in "Couldn't find theme resource DirectoryRowBackground for current theme", that is regardless if I put it as:

```
android:background="?attrs/DirectoryRowBackground"
```

or

```
android:background="?DirectoryRowBackground"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your RelativeLayout. It should be **attr** instead of **attrs**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="?attr/DirectoryRowBackground"
android:id="@+id/cale"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="bottom" >
```

Comment: Ah, that solves it. I still have:

10-11 14:58:03.138: E/AndroidRuntime(10369): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>

but I guess I will solve it eventually